# Flutter Table Calender Customized Desing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, table-calendar

Hello Guys I want to achive this design in my flutter app but I dosen't know how to do that?

Design want to achive-

[image: Design image]

My code -

```
TableCalendar(
calendarFormat: CalendarFormat.week,
headerVisible: false,
focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
firstDay: DateTime.utc(DateTime.monthsPerYear,),
lastDay: DateTime.utc(2022, 8, 31),);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't come across this pub before (so thanks for the introduction!) but just from reading the documentation, it seems like you can customise the UI for your Calendar by using a CalendarBuilder param `calendarBuilders`.

You can then build a custom widget for the various components you want to achieve

See [this link](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar#custom-ui-with-calendarbuilders) from the TableCalendar doc

And here is the documentation for the CalendarBuilder [enter link description here](https://pub.dev/documentation/table_calendar/latest/table_calendar/CalendarBuilders-class.html)

I assume you're going to need the [dowBuilder](https://pub.dev/documentation/table_calendar/latest/table_calendar/CalendarBuilders/dowBuilder.html) and the [markerBuilder](https://pub.dev/documentation/table_calendar/latest/table_calendar/CalendarBuilders/markerBuilder.html)

Comment: Thank you @Dhen Padila it's really so helpful for me

Answer (score -1):

You can design it by own using container in rows but it is difficult.
You can use any package for it from pub.dev